# Why this code is everytime generating 0000-0000 as guid?

Tags: c#

Why this code is everytime generating 0000-0000 as guid?

```
 static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            Guid obj = new Guid();
            Console.WriteLine("New Guid is " + obj.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Comment: Because it is a constructor of a structure not a GUID generator

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The simple answer here is to Read The Friendly Manual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to do following to get new Guid.

```
  Guid.NewGuid()
```

By default it is blank.

Answer (score 4):

```
new Guid();
```

This just instantiates a new structure of Guid. It doesn't generate any values for it.

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) docs:

> Initializes a new instance of the Guid structure.

To get a new GUID each time with a new value:

```
Guid.NewGuid();
```

To test whether you have a new Guid or not, you can use the `Guid.Empty`

```
if (myGuid == Guid.Empty())
```

---

***Aside***

Here's another interesting snippet, I've been told for value types to always use `==` to do equality comparing, and for reference types you can do `.Equals()`. However, looking under the hood of the Guid implementation, it seems very safe to use `.Equals()`:

```
    public bool Equals(Guid g)
    {
        // Now compare each of the elements
        if(g._a != _a)
            return false;
        if(g._b != _b)
            return false;
        if(g._c != _c)
            return false;
        if (g._d != _d)
            return false;
        if (g._e != _e)
            return false;
        if (g._f != _f)
            return false;
        if (g._g != _g)
            return false;
        if (g._h != _h)
            return false;
        if (g._i != _i)
            return false;
        if (g._j != _j)
            return false;
        if (g._k != _k)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

I don't know about anyone else, I've always been interested in whether you should do `==` or `.Equals()`